# How to sort a multidimensional array with values from multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, perl

I am developing a test which will give a result of 2 values

```
$result = array( 't' => 10, 's' => 20 );
```

and i have ranges that will give a response as badge name from array to that result:

```
$badges = array(
    'badge1' => array(
        array('tLow' => 0, 'tHigh' => 20),
        array('sLow' => 0, 'sHigh' => 10)
    ),
    'badge2' => array(
        array('tLow' => 0, 'tHigh' => 10),
        array('sLow' => 11, 'sHigh' => 20)
    ),
    'badge3' => array(
        array('tLow' => 21, 'tHigh' => 30),
        array('sLow' => 0, 'sHigh' => 10)
    ),
    'badge4' => array(
        array('tLow' => 31, 'tHigh' => 40),
        array('sLow' => 0, 'sHigh' => 10)
    ),
    'badge5' => array(
        array('tLow' => 11, 'tHigh' => 30),
        array('sLow' => 11, 'sHigh' => 30)
    ),
    'badge6' => array(
        array('tLow' => 0, 'tHigh' => 10),
        array('sLow' => 21, 'sHigh' => 30)
    ),
    'badge7' => array(
        array('tLow' => 0, 'tHigh' => 10),
        array('sLow' => 31, 'sHigh' => 40)
    ),
);
```

badge arrays correspond to a grid which looks like this

```
+---+
| 7 |
+---+---+---+
| 6 |       |
+---+   5   +
| 2 |       |
+---+---+---+---+
|   1   | 3 | 4 |
+---+---+---+---+
```

so my question is what is the most effective way to get a badge for my result? maybe there is a better approach to this?

Comment: Please add appropriate language tag.

Comment: i don't think it is language dependent in any way and i am fine with pseudo code. I dont want to filter out people who don't appreciate PHP :)

Comment: OK - there's a `language-agnostic` tag for that kind of question, but you should probably use pseudo code if the question is truly language agnostic, as not everyone can read php/perl/whatever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of the top of my head you could do something like this.

```
foreach ($badges as $key => $badge)
{
   if ($result['t'] >= $badge[0]['tLow'] && $result['t'] <= $badge[0]['tHigh'])
   {
      // t matches
      if ($result['s'] >= $badge[0]['sLow'] && $result['s'] <= $badge[0]['sHigh'])
      { 
         // s matches
         echo 'Badge was found: '.$key;
         break;
      }
   }
}
```

This code was not tested. But should work

Comment: If you change `$badge['tLow']` to `$badge[0]['tLow']` and 3 others by same pattern in the if statments it will work fine.  Also after echo its wise to put a break; statement so it stops after it finds something. Other than that thanks a lot!